# COMBINE TWO SQL QUERY TO GIVE TWO COLUMNS- IN ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different set of queries that I need to merge into two different columns.

DURATION

```
select 
  sum(duration),
  pps.person_id
from 
    anc_per_abs_entries apae,
    anc_absence_types_vl abs,
    per_periods_of_service pps,
    anc_absence_type_reasons_f abtype,
    anc_absence_reasons_f_tl ab_reason

where 1=1
  AND (To_Char(apae.start_date  ,'YYYY-MM-DD') Between to_date(To_Char(:From_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') And to_date(To_Char(:To_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') )
  AND apae.APPROVAL_STATUS_CD = 'APPROVED'
  AND apae.ABSENCE_STATUS_CD = 'SUBMITTED'
  and abs.name like  'Paid Personal Leave' 
  AND apae.period_of_service_id = pps.period_of_service_id
  AND apae.absence_type_id = abs.absence_type_id
  AND abtype.absence_type_id = abs.absence_type_id
  AND ab_reason.absence_reason_id = abtype.absence_reason_id
  AND apae.absence_type_reason_id = abtype.absence_type_reason_id
  AND pps.person_id = papf.person_id  
group by pps.person_id
```

MEASURE

```
select sum(measure)
from
    time_track rec ,
    time_type rec_type,
    per_all_people_f papf
where 1=1
  AND rec_type.tm_bldg_blk_version = rec.tm_rec_version
  AND rec.tm_rec_type IN ( 'RANGE', 'MEASURE' )
  AND (to_date(To_Char(rec.START_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') Between to_date(To_Char(:From_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') And to_date(To_Char(:To_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') )
  and papf.person_id = rec.person_id
```

The from_date and to_date are the parameters and these two queries should form two different columns of my result set. My expected result is -

```
person_number                      duration                                 measure
73636                               10                                       8
```

i.e. duration is from QUERY 1 AND MEASURE Is from QUERY 2. These two queries require calculations and are getting affected or manipulated if i use as 2 subqueries in one single query.
Since say for example paid personal leave will have duration on 01-Jan-2020 but it will not have "Measure" but still it will come in the result output.

How can i combine THESE TWO TO FORM A RESULT OUTPUT IN TWO DIFFERENT COLUMNS

QUERY 1               QUERY 2           person_id

Common link is person_id. When used in subquery, it is giving more than 1 row in subquery error as there can be multiple values within the date range.

Comment: The short answer is "use a JOIN". Just how that join should look depends on three  things. 1. Which table has the column "duration" ? 2. Which table has the column "measure" ?. 3. Do both tables have the person_id? The SQL has obviously been generated by some program. Is that program to be used for the join? or is this something to be done by hand? It would be helpful to know what the tables involved actually look like.

Comment: You do not have `person_id` in the output of the second query. If you would, then just join them on `person_id`. Please show your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the queries you have shown work as you describe, then the following, whilst not pretty, should do the trick.

```
SELECT T1.PERSONID, T1.DURATION, T2.MEASURE
FROM
(select 
  sum(duration) AS DURATION,
  pps.person_id AS PERSONID
from 
    anc_per_abs_entries apae,
    anc_absence_types_vl abs,
    per_periods_of_service pps,
    anc_absence_type_reasons_f abtype,
    anc_absence_reasons_f_tl ab_reason

where 1=1
  AND (To_Char(apae.start_date  ,'YYYY-MM-DD') Between to_date(To_Char(:From_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') And to_date(To_Char(:To_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') )
  AND apae.APPROVAL_STATUS_CD = 'APPROVED'
  AND apae.ABSENCE_STATUS_CD = 'SUBMITTED'
  and abs.name like  'Paid Personal Leave' 
  AND apae.period_of_service_id = pps.period_of_service_id
  AND apae.absence_type_id = abs.absence_type_id
  AND abtype.absence_type_id = abs.absence_type_id
  AND ab_reason.absence_reason_id = abtype.absence_reason_id
  AND apae.absence_type_reason_id = abtype.absence_type_reason_id
  AND pps.person_id = papf.person_id  
group by pps.person_id) T1
JOIN
(select 
   rec.person_id AS PERSONID
   sum(measure) AS MEASURE
from
    time_track rec ,
    time_type rec_type,
    per_all_people_f papf
where 1=1
  AND rec_type.tm_bldg_blk_version = rec.tm_rec_version
  AND rec.tm_rec_type IN ( 'RANGE', 'MEASURE' )
  AND (to_date(To_Char(rec.START_TIME,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') Between to_date(To_Char(:From_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') And to_date(To_Char(:To_Date,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') )
  and papf.person_id = rec.person_id) T2
ON T1.PERSONID = T2.PERSONID
```

BTW: the condition `1=1` can be removed from both sub-selects. It actually does nothing in this case.

Comment: There may be cases when measure or duration is not there for a employee. Will this query still return a value ? Say for example "Measure" is not there in the table, but duration is there within a range. Then iwll the above query return duration since its join and not left/right join ?

Comment: When you say "measure is not there" I assume you mean the value is null. The joined table is defined with sum(measure), so the resulting "MEASURE" would be zero if all the summed measure values are null. Same goes for duration. The Oracle specs are to be found at: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions163.htm. There is a simpler explanation at https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-aggregate-functions/oracle-sum/